# Not able to exit the child process properly using condition variable after handling a SIGTERM

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable, sigterm

I have created a child process where I am handling a `SIGTERM` sent from the parent process. In the child process I am waiting on a *condition_variable* `cv` inside a new thread `waitingForWork()`. `cv` is set by the `SIGTERM` signal handler inside `stopTheWait()` function.

For some reason the `stopTheWait()` function cannot acquire the `lock` and `waitingForWork()` waits for ever and `doTheCleanUp()` is never called.

Finally the Parent process closes.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable


std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void stopTheWait(){
    printf("[CHILD] Stopping the wait.. \n\n");
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.notify_all();
}

void signal_callback_handler(int signum)
{
   printf("[CHILD] Caught signal, trying to stop the wait... %d\n\n",signum);
   stopTheWait();
}

void doTheCleanUp()/* is never called*/ {
    printf("[CHILD] clean up... \n\n");
}

void waitingForWork(){
    printf("[CHILD] wait for ever... \n\n");

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait(lck);
    doTheCleanUp();
    printf("[CHILD] clean Up Done, now end wait... \n\n");
    exit(0);
}


int main()
{
    printf("[PARENT] in parent...\n");
    int pid;
   if ((pid = fork()) < 0) { 
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 
    
   if (pid == 0) 
    { /* child */
        signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback_handler);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

        std::thread t1(waitingForWork);
        t1.join();
        
        waitingForWork();
        printf("[CHILD] wait is over...\n\n");
    } 

    else /* parent */
    { /* pid hold id of child */

        sleep(3); /* pause for 3 secs */
        printf("[PARENT] sending SIGTERM\n\n"); 
        kill(pid, SIGTERM); 
        sleep(3);
    } 

   printf("[PARENT] exiting parent...\n");
   sleep(1);
   
   return 0;
}
```

I see below print.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **[support.signal]/3** An evaluation is *signal-safe* unless it includes one of the following:
>
> (3.1) — a call to any standard library function, except for plain lock-free atomic operations and functions explicitly identified as signal-safe.
> ...
>
> A signal handler invocation has undefined behavior if it includes an evaluation that is not signal-safe.

There's very little one can safely do in a signal handler. `printf`, mutex and condition variable operations are right out.